Question about the topology of subsets of Euclidean spaces
As a consequence of the famous Riemann Mapping Theorem, all simply connected domain are homeomorphic. I wonder if there is any higher dimensional analogue of this.
For example, if an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has all homotopy(or homology) groups trivial, is it necessarily homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?
This leads to another question: in the 2-dimensional case, does $H_1(U)$ being trivial imply $U$ is simply connected?

The answer to the second question is yes (if you assume $U$ to be connected) because the fundamental group of an open subset of the plane is free, see this MO question.

See this and all the links in the comments for some pretty detailed information about the first question!
